# behavior of undefined with respect to objects

Tags: javascript

So I was playing around with objects and I noticed that for object `a = {}`

`a.b == undefined` is `true`

`a.b === undefined` is also `true`

however
`a.b === (undefined || 'c')` is `false`

Does anyone knows what is the reason for that behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`undefined || 'c'` evaluates to `'c'`, so `a.b === (undefined || 'c')` is equivalent to running `a.b === 'c'`, which is clearly false.

Here is the MDN documentation on logical operators for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

In particular:

> **Operator**: Logical OR (||)
>   **Usage**: *expr1* || *expr2*
>   **Description**: Returns *expr1* if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns *expr2*. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

In the case of `undefined || 'c'`, `undefined` cannot be converted to true so `'c'` is returned by the `||` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`a.b === (undefined || 'c')`

`a.b` is `undefined` like you mentioned.

The `||` or operator will return its left side if it's true; otherwise it'll return its' right side.

In this case, `(undefined || 'c')` evaluates to `'c'`, leaving you with `a.b === 'c'`, which is false.